# Css of div with dynamic value of id?

Tags: jquery

I have two or more sections on a webpage.  But here I am taking only two Photo sections for example. For every section I have given a email icon link with same class name "divclasss" with different ids like clicki6524 , clicki6525. For every section I have a hidden div consecutively dclicki6524 and dclicki6525.

Now I want to display these hidden div by click on the email icon link in their particular section. But now able to do so. You can look these two section [here](http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/us_portfolio/week-1/).

Some time this work only when I give static div value #dclicki624 in the below code for css. But I dont want to give static value because the div id is comming dynamically and they can be two or more. Any help will be appreciated.

The jquery  code I am  using is:

```
$('.divclasss').click(function(){
var a = 'd' + this.id;

$("#a").css({"display":"block",
                "top":"10%",
                "position":"fixed",
                "background":"#333",
                "border-radius":"5px",
                "padding":"10px",
                "color":"#fff"
                });


});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `$("#"+a)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating the string wrongly,

```
$("#"+a)
```

And i would suggest you to the class `divClass` at this context since the `css` rules for all the `div` elements are same.

Simply do in your css like,

```
.divclasss{
  display:block;
  top:10%;
  position:fixed;
  background:#333;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @user3777827 Glad to help..! and if you feel that any one of the answers here has solved your problem then try to click on the tick mark available on the top left corner of the answer.. And it is not a compulsion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, you are fetching the first element that has 'a' id, not the value of a variable. Try this

```
$("#"+a).css({"display":"block",
            "top":"10%",
            "position":"fixed",
            "background":"#333",
            "border-radius":"5px",
            "padding":"10px",
            "color":"#fff"
            });
});
```

Comment: its working, Thanks .. I am a php developer and I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You are using id selector in wrong way, as 'a' is a variable and you are putting it in string. You should concatenate '#' with variable 'a'. Use like this :

```
$('.divclasss').click(function(){
var a = 'd' + this.id;

$("#"+a).css({"display":"block",
                "top":"10%",
                "position":"fixed",
                "background":"#333",
                "border-radius":"5px",
                "padding":"10px",
                "color":"#fff"
                });


});
```